# VBA- Delete row if value is not a Duplicate and keep all rows with duplicate values

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I've been working on a VBA script for a while now that goes through the values of a column and deletes all rows with values appearing only once (pretty much the inverse of deleting duplicates).

[Column Headers to make explanation easier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOjPt.png)

There are numbers in the 'VTR' column that appear more than once. most appear just once. 
I'd like the macro to delete all rows where the number in the 'VTR' column appears only once.(in the case of one of these numbers appearing more than once, the difference lies at the 'AFTARTKRZ' column where the value can either be (GAPNK or GAPN2) or RSLNV or RSVNK. (GAPNK or GAPN2 are the same thing)

i.e a row can appear either **once** with AFTARTKRZ,

(GAPNK or GAPN2)

-**OR twice**

**either** (GAPNKorGAPN2), RSLNV 
**or** (GAPNKorGAPN2), RSVNK

**OR thrice**
(GAPNK or GAPN2), RSLNV, RSVNK.

I'd like to delete all those that appear only once (GAPNKorGAPN2)

Furthermore, I'd like to then add the values of the 'AFTARTKRZ' values of the duplicates to 2 extra columns at the end. 
i.e, when a (GAPNK or GAPN2) appears two or threee other times, I'd like to input the 'AFTARTKRZ' column value in the 2 last columns at the end.

Something like this should be the final result

```
VTR|AFTARTKRZ | Add1     | Add2
11 |GAPNK     |RSLNV     | RSVNK|  - VTR appeared thrice
12 |GAPN2     |RSLNV     |      |  - Appeared twice as (GAPNKorGAPN2), RSLNV 
13 |GAPNK     |RSVNK     |      |  - Appeared twice as (GAPNKorGAPN2), RSVNK
14 |GAPN2     |          | 
15 |GAPNK     |          | 
16 |GAPN2     |          |
```

The relevant part begins at  '~~~~ Work on A

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim RowsToTestC As Range, Delrange As Range
    Dim i As Long, Lrow As Long, Lop As Long

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)    
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "A"

    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)    
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "B"

    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)    
    ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "C"    
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

    '~~~~ Work on C    
    Worksheets("C").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AQ").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=6, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    Worksheets("C").Activate    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Delete all but RSV
    For Lrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("D" & Lrow).Value = "GAPNK" Or Range("D" & Lrow) = "GAPN2" Then
            Rows(Lrow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Lrow

    '~~~~ Work on B
     Worksheets("B").Activate      
     With ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A:AQ").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=6, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    Worksheets("B").Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '~~> Delete all but GAP
    For Lrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("D" & Lrow).Value = "RSVNK" Or Range("D" & Lrow) = "RSLNV" Then
            Rows(Lrow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Lrow        

     '~~~~ Work on A
     Worksheets("A").Activate

     Range("AR1").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "RSVNK"
     Range("AS1").Select
     ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "RSLNV"        

     With ws1
        '~~> Get the last row which has data in Col A
        Lop = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop through the rows
        For i = 2 To Lop
            '~~> For for multiple occurances
            If .Cells(i, 6).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(6), .Cells(i, 6)) = 1 And _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(4), .Cells(i, 4)) = 1 Then
                    '~~> Store thee row in a temp range
                    If Delrange Is Nothing Then
                        Set Delrange = .Rows(i)
                    Else
                        Set Delrange = Union(Delrange, .Rows(i))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you are encountering in your code? We can't really help you debug unless you present a specific problem or error and where it is occurring. Also, in general using the .Activate and .Select commands will lead you to problems.

Comment: Hi SandPiper. Thanks for the reply. The issue lies at the work on A part of my code. The last part. It just sort of doesn't do anything. I'd like it to first loop through the rows of a column(vtr) and delete all complete rows where the number present in that column is a non-duplicate(appears only once). Depending on how many duplicates are left behind it then adds data from the others in the last 2 columns of one of the duplicates(say,  the first)  and deletes the rest of the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your code isn't valid.

The condition `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Columns(4), .Cells(i, 4)) = 1` will always be `False` because this is the column containing your AFTARTKRZ keys. I don't know how many rows of data you have, but even in the 10 row sample you gave us the result is always greater than 1.

I do think you're making this unnecessarily complicated. Aren't you just trying to populate two lists: one of GAPs and the other of RSVs? You then want to create a third list where the GAP entries have corresponding RSV entries?

That could be done in a couple of short routines. You could do away with all of your sheet copying and row deleting and simply write your three lists directly to your sheets.

The code below shows you how this could be done. I've created 4 sheets, so you may need to add another to your Workbook: `Sheet1` is your summary list (A), `Sheet2` is your GAP list (B), `Sheet3` is your RSV list (C), and `Sheet4` holds the raw data.

Hopefully this code can get you started:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RunMe()
    Const AFTARTKRZ_COL As Long = 4
    Const VTR_COL As Long = 6
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim GAPs As Collection
    Dim RSVs As Collection
    Dim multis As Collection
    Dim vtrKey As String
    Dim multi(0 To 1) As Long
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim countRSV As Long
    Dim output() As Variant

    'Name your sheets.
    'If you have fewer than 3 sheets or
    'sheets already names A, B, C then this
    'will throw an error.
    Sheet1.Name = "A"
    Sheet2.Name = "B"
    Sheet3.Name = "C"

    'Initialise the 3 collections
    Set GAPs = New Collection
    Set RSVs = New Collection
    Set multis = New Collection

    'Read the data - I've put my dummy data on Sheet4
    data = Sheet4.UsedRange.Value2
    'Iterate rows and place row in relevant collection
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        vtrKey = CStr(data(r, VTR_COL))
        On Error Resume Next 'removes duplicate entries
        Select Case data(r, AFTARTKRZ_COL)
            Case Is = "GAPNK", "GAPN2": GAPs.Add r, vtrKey
            Case Is = "RSLNV": RSVs.Add r, vtrKey & "|RSLNV"
            Case Is = "RSVNK": RSVs.Add r, vtrKey & "|RSVNK"
        End Select
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    'Check if each GAP also has RSVs
    For Each v In GAPs
        vtrKey = CStr(data(v, VTR_COL))
        countRSV = 0
        If Exists(RSVs, vtrKey & "|RSLNV") Then countRSV = countRSV + 1
        If Exists(RSVs, vtrKey & "|RSVNK") Then countRSV = countRSV + 2
        If countRSV > 0 Then
            multi(0) = CLng(v)
            multi(1) = countRSV
            multis.Add multi, vtrKey
        End If
    Next

    'Write your outputs
    'Sheet C
    ReDim output(1 To RSVs.Count + 1, 1 To UBound(data, 2))
    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        output(1, c) = data(1, c)
    Next
    i = 2
    For Each v In RSVs
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            output(i, c) = data(v, c)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With Sheet3
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    'Sheet B
    ReDim output(1 To GAPs.Count + 1, 1 To UBound(data, 2))
    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
        output(1, c) = data(1, c)
    Next
    i = 2
    For Each v In GAPs
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            output(i, c) = data(v, c)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With Sheet2
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    'Sheet A
    ReDim output(1 To multis.Count + 1, 1 To 5)
    output(1, 1) = "VTR"
    output(1, 2) = "AFTARTKRZ"
    output(1, 3) = "Add1"
    output(1, 4) = "Add2"
    i = 2
    For Each v In multis
        r = v(0)
        output(i, 1) = data(r, VTR_COL)
        output(i, 2) = data(r, AFTARTKRZ_COL)
        output(i, 2) = data(r, AFTARTKRZ_COL)
        Select Case v(1)
            Case 1
                output(i, 3) = "RSLNV"
                output(i, 5) = "Appeared twice as (GAPNK or GAPN2), RSLNV"
            Case 2
                output(i, 3) = "RSVNK"
                output(i, 5) = "Appeared twice as (GAPNK or GAPN2), RSVNK"
            Case 3
                output(i, 3) = "RSLNV"
                output(i, 4) = "RSVNK"
                output(i, 5) = "VTR appeared thrice"
        End Select
        i = i + 1
    Next

    With Sheet1
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub
Private Function Exists(col As Collection, key As String) As Boolean
    Dim v As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    v = col(key)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exists = Not IsEmpty(v)

End Function
```